# ¿El orden de las condiciones en un WHERE cambia la eficiencia de la consulta?

Tags: sql

Si tengo una consulta del tipo:

```
SELECT a, b FROM c WHERE a = 5 and b LIKE '%foo%'
```

Y tengo otra:

```
SELECT a, b FROM c WHERE b LIKE '%foo%' and a = 5
```

He ejecutado ambas y las dos tienen el mismo tiempo de ejecución, pero en cuanto el consumo de recursos, ¿alguna es más eficiente que la otra?

Comment: No, no hay ningún cambio en el performance, tiempo de ejecución o cualquier otro factor. De hecho, el manejador de base de datos evalúa las condiciones y las acomoda para tener la consulta más óptima, una vez que se han acomodado las condiciones se ejecuta la consulta.

Comment: Es justo como las multiplicaciones, el orden del los factores no altera el producto, así mismo aquí, el tiempo de ejecución y el consumo de recursos es el mismo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No realmente, sin importar el orden en que escribas las claúsulas del `WHERE`, SQL priorizará la columna por índices en la tabla. Haría mas incapié sobre el `LIKE` en todo caso, ya que con relación al `WHERE` es menos eficiente por la lectura de la columna condicionada.

En un peor escenario tendríamos a las claúsulas `WHERE` que comparten una función, por ejemplo:

```
WHERE anio = YEAR(date);
```

En todo caso si lo que buscas es optimizar tus claúsulas en el `WHERE` piensa primero en usar los índices de la tabla y no usar funciones para comparar.

Answer (score 3):

Tienen el mismo tiempo de ejecución porque ambas condiciones se tienen que procesar para cada registro

Por ejemplo:

Como tienes `a=5` y `b LIKE '%foo%'` con la expresión lógica `and` se tienen que comprobar ambas para que un registro se evalué correctamente

Solo al encontrar la primera condición **falsa** no se evaluan ambas condiciones.

Si cambiamos por un `OR` sí que cambiaría el tiempo, en este caso

```
SELECT a, b FROM c WHERE a=5 OR b LIKE '%foo%'
```

Al encontrar la primera condición **verdadera** no hay porque seguir evaluando los demás.

En este caso buscar `a=5` es menos costoso que `b LIKE '%foo%'` así que en este orden, el mejor de los casos los registros con `a=5` tendrán un menor tiempo de búsqueda. Si ningún registro cumple con la primera condición se tendría que evaluar la segunda (Peor de los casos)

Esto lo podemos apreciar más con funciones más complejas

```
SELECT a, b FROM c WHERE a=5 OR  funcionCompleja(b) -- Mejor rendimiento

SELECT a, b FROM c WHERE funcionCompleja(b) OR a=5  -- Peor rendimiento
```

---

Hagamos otro ejercicio

Voy a crear una función que solo tenga un sleep para simular complejidad y que siempre regrese 1

```
CREATE FUNCTION `funcionCompleja`() RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN

DO SLEEP(5);

RETURN 1;
END
```

Voy a rellenar mi tabla con diez datos

```
1 | 5 | basura
2 | 5 | basura
3 | 5 | basura
4 | 5 | basura
5 | 5 | basura
6 | 5 | basura
7 | 5 | basura
8 | 5 | basura
9 | 5 | basura
10 | 5 | basura
```

Nótese `a` es siempre 5

Si ejecuto

```
SELECT a, b FROM c WHERE a=5 OR  funcionCompleja(b) = 1
```

Tarda 0.000 sec

Si ejecuto

```
SELECT a, b FROM c WHERE  funcionCompleja(b) = 1 OR a=5
```

Tarda 49.998 sec

Porque primero ejecuta la `funcionCompleja`

Si ejecuto

```
SELECT a, b FROM c WHERE  funcionCompleja(b) = 1 AND a=5
```

Tarda 50.014 sec (Aunque se debe considerar que simpre es 50 segundos)
Porque se evalúan ambas

Si ejecuto

```
SELECT a, b FROM c WHERE  a=0  and funcionCompleja(b) = 1
```

Tarda 0.000 sec

Porque no tiene sentido evaluar la siguiente condición

---

Como regla se podría decir que se debería preguntar por lo más simple (rápido) antes

Comment: Este fue mi razonamiento inicial, pero he realizado las pruebas y al menos en `mysql` no sucede de esta manera.